# How can I import an csv file into SQLite3 from within Python using subprocess

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I'm currently running legacy code that attempts to convert a csv file into a SQL database from within Python. The file is too big for Pandas, so the code is running sqlite3 in a Python subprocess like this:

```
    result = subprocess.run(["sqlite3", str(db_name), '-cmd', ".mode csv",
                             '.import '+str(csv).replace('\\','\\\\')
                             +'_nohead ships'], shell=True, capture_output=True)
```

However, things seem to hang when running this statement. I've checked its progress from the shell using:

```
ps -ef| egrep "sqlite3|PID"
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
smg       583476  583406  0 12:31 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sqlite3 /media/me/Fortress/ais.db -cmd .mode csv .import /media/me/Fortress/ais/AIS_2016_03_Zone10.csv_nohead ships
```

But it's been running almost 3 hours so far, which seems incorrect. Is there something wrong with the command created by this subprocess, or for a 3.3GB file, should I just expect it to take that long?

===== EDIT =========

I just tried with a csv file that I reduced to 10 lines and it still hangs !!????

This is legacy code, this much of it should still work. What am I failing to understand here?

Comment: Maybe check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite-database-table-using-python/) out?

Comment: It probably should be something like `sqlite3 -cmd '.mode csv'  -cmd  '.import /media/me/Fortress/ais/AIS_2016_03_Zone10.csv_nohead ships'  /media/me/Fortress/ais.db`

Comment: By using `shell=True`, you're passing the list of args to a shell process, which processes them and separates them, resulting in only the database name, assuming it has no spaces in it, being passed to sqlite3.  Either pass the entire command as one string with args that have spaces quoted, or simply drop `shell=True`

Comment: @Anon Coward - Yes, that seems to be the problem